# 'ORA-01002 fetch out of sequence' when fetching from cursor based on truncated temporary table

Tags: oracle, temp-tables, database-cursor, oracle19c, truncation

I have a PLSQL function which opens new cursor based on join of persistent table with temporary table. Every time the new cursor is created, the temporary table is truncated and filled with data (the content of temporary table is subset of ids in persistent table - it is actually result of computation of complex search query), each in own autonomous transaction.

Let's create two cursors. First cursor reads half of data, then second cursor reads all data and closes, then the first cursor tries to read remaining data. The attempt of reading remaining data fails with `ORA-01002 fetch out of sequence` error. The wrong behaviour is observed on Oracle 19.0.0.0.0 (our db) and 19.14.0.0.0 (LiveSQL) but not on Oracle 11 (our previous version).

Minimized example:

```sql
create global temporary table temp_table (
  id number(38,0)
) on commit preserve rows;

create table data_table (
  id number(38,0),
  val varchar2(10)
);

insert into data_table 
select 1, 'a' from dual union all
select 2, 'b' from dual union all
select 3, 'c' from dual union all
select 4, 'd' from dual;

declare

type ref_cursor is ref cursor;

procedure storeToTempTable
is
  cmd varchar2(32767);
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  cmd := q'[
    insert into temp_table (id)
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual
  ]';
  execute immediate cmd;
  commit;
end;

procedure truncateTempTable
is
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  execute immediate 'truncate table temp_table';
end;

function getCursor return ref_cursor
is
  cur      ref_cursor;
  q  varchar2(32767);
begin
  truncateTempTable;
  storeToTempTable;
  q := 'select r.* from data_table r, temp_table t where r.id = t.id';
  open cur for q;
  return cur;
end;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

begin -- main
 
declare
  cursor1 ref_cursor;
  cursor2 ref_cursor;
  dto data_table%rowtype;
  i1 pls_integer := 0;
  i2 pls_integer := 0;
begin
  cursor1 := getCursor;
  loop
    exit when i1 = 2;
    i1 := i1 + 1;
    fetch cursor1 into dto;
    exit when cursor1%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('i1 = ' || i1 || ', dto.id = ' || dto.id);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('not closing 1');
  --dont close cursor1;

  cursor2 := getCursor;
  loop
    i2 := i2 + 1;
    fetch cursor2 into dto;
    exit when cursor2%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('i2 = ' || i2 || ', dto.id = ' || dto.id);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('closing 2');
  close cursor2;

  loop
    i1 := i1 + 1;
    fetch cursor1 into dto;
    exit when cursor1%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('i1 = ' || i1 || ', dto.id = ' || dto.id);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('closing 1');
  close cursor1;
end;

end;
/
```

I guess the table truncation somehow invalidates `cursor1` during creation of `cursor2`. I don't have a clue why this worked in previous version (I actually wonder it worked.)

I also figured out a workaround - to replace body of `truncateTempTable` procedure for `execute immediate 'delete from temp_table'; commit;`. (Commit is necessary, otherwise [ORA-06519 appears](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06519_active_autonomous_transaction_detected_and_rolled_back.html).) With the workaround, scripts provides correct result:

```
Table created.
Table created.
4 row(s) inserted.
Statement processed.
i1 = 1, dto.id = 1
i1 = 2, dto.id = 2
not closing 1
i2 = 1, dto.id = 1
i2 = 2, dto.id = 2
i2 = 3, dto.id = 3
i2 = 4, dto.id = 4
closing 2
i1 = 3, dto.id = 3
i1 = 4, dto.id = 4
closing 1
```

My question is if there is some support in documentation for such behavior and correctness of proposed workaround.

[LiveSQL demo here.](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/of16v6xsyz9cye6vjgzyeocli) (no dbfiddle, sorry - [attempts](https://dbfiddle.uk/AiWiHiPb) on 18c either fail or return even different results)

Comment: Why are you using `autonomous_transaction` at all? The data you're adding/deleting had to be visible to the current session, and is *only* visible to that, so autonomous+commit seems... a bit pointless? As does dynamic SQL - why not just do a simple static insert and delete - [as in this 21c fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xs7mXVfj)? (I don't seem to be able to see your LiveSQL demo...)

Comment: @AlexPoole (1) I fixed wrong Livesql link to shareable one. (2) The static insert is not possible - it is actually very complex query where parts of `from` clause and `where` clause are generated dynamically depending on various conditions. It is theoretically possible to merge them into one big universal query but in that case its performance would probably heavily decrease. (3) The exact reason of autonomous transaction is unknown to me in this moment (it is legacy code I am not author of, I have just to fix bug), however without it (and with dynamic query) the error remains as well.